# Compare all lists in a dictonary to each other

Tags: python, python-object

In python is it possible to compare all objects in the following structure

I have a dictionary of lists and each list has objects in it e.g.

```
[
      [object1,object2,object3],
      [object4,object5,object6],
      [object7,object8,object9],
]
```

I want to compare all objects by a attribute in each list to each other and identify what objects are not in each list.

**Based on the feedback please see an example below**

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

class mytest:
  def __init__(self, no, description):
    self.no = no
    self.description = description

data = []


x = mytest(1,'test1')
x2 = mytest(2,'test1')

x3 = mytest(1,'test2')
x4 = mytest(2,'test2')
x5 = mytest(3,'test2')


x6 = mytest(1,'test3')
x7 = mytest(2,'test3')
x8 = mytest(4,'test3')


data.append(x)
data.append(x2)
data.append(x3)
data.append(x4)
data.append(x5)
data.append(x6)
data.append(x7)
data.append(x8)


groups = defaultdict(list)

for obj in data:
    groups[obj.description].append(obj)

new_list = groups.values()


#i want to find out what items are not in each list
for list in new_list:
    pprint(list)


#example x8 = mytest(4,'test3') is only in one of the list so is missing from list 1 and 2
```

hopefully this helps

Comment: This appears to be a list of lists, not a dictionary of lists.

Comment: @jpp i have added an example hope this helps

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell you are correct it is a list of lists

Comment: Do you want to know which objects are missing from each list, or which numbers (self.no) are missing?

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell  which numbers (self.no) are missing from each lis,t although objects would work too ideally i just need a list of what is missing between the lists thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. We create a set of the possible values of `obj.no` and then use the set difference operator ( using `-` on two sets, to get the elements missing).

```
# Get a set of all the no. values present in the data.
combined_set_of_values = set([item.no for item in data])

# Get the sets of obj.no values grouped by description.
for obj in data:
    groups[obj.description].append(obj.no)

new_list = groups.values()


# Print the list, and the elements missing from that list
for list in new_list:
    print("Values in list:")
    print(list)
    # Use set difference to see what's missing from list.
    print("Missing from list:")
    print(combined_set_of_values - set(list))
```

This gives an output of:

```
Values in list:
[1, 2]
Missing from list:
{3, 4}
Values in list:
[1, 2, 3]
Missing from list:
{4}
Values in list:
[1, 2, 4]
Missing from list:
{3}
```

Comment: Thank you very much just what i was looking for :)

Comment: No problem. Thank you for editing your question to make it clearer!